# Django cant find static files

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-templates

I am trying to build a forum with Django. I want to use an animated background with particles.js. When I write this code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Particles login</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
  <div id="particles-js">

  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json', function(){
      console.log('particles.json loaded...');
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and run it on live server I get what I want. However, I tweaked the code for Django:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
</head>

<body>
{% include 'snippets/base_css.html' %}
{% include 'snippets/header.html' %}




<!-- Body -->
<style type="text/css">
    .main{
        min-height: 100vh;
        height: 100%;
    }
    

    #particles-js{
      height: 100%;
      color:turquoise;
 
}


</style>
<div class="main">
    <div id="particles-js">
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json', function(){
      console.log('particles.json loaded...');
    });
  </script>
        
    

    

    {% block content %}

    {% endblock content %}
</div>

</div>
<!-- End Body -->

{% include 'snippets/footer.html' %}

</body>


</html>
```

When I  run this with Django. I get the following error even though the locations of those files are exactly the same:

```
Not Found: /style.css
[28/May/2021 00:21:59] "GET /style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2263
Not Found: /particles.json
[28/May/2021 00:21:59] "GET /particles.json HTTP/1.1" 404 2278
```

Can someone please enlighten me about this issue? Should I add something to static files in settings.py?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in **settings.py**, add this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    "<PATH_TO_YOUR_STATIC_DIR>"
]
```

Then at the beginning of your HTML file, write `{% load static %}`

After that, wherever you want to reference a static file, do so by making use of the following syntax: `{% static 'PATH_TO_STATIC_FILE' %}`

For example,
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" />`
Do this if you're keeping your style.css file in "css" directory. If not, then directly write `{% static 'style.css' %}`